# How to group from COALESCE? SQL

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
    VehicleOwner,
    COALESCE(CarMileage, MotorcycleMileage, BicycleMileage, 0) AS Mileage,
    Count(*)
FROM
    VehicleMileage
Group by VehicleOwner
Having Count(*)>1
```

Comment: What database? What is the problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `COALESCE` already groups, since it will first set `CarMileage` As `Mileage`, if doesn't exist then `MotorcycleMileage` As `Mileage` of doesn't exist then `BicycleMileage` As `Mileage`

Comment: How does this question still exist on this site in this form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...

```
SELECT b.VehicleOwner, City
FROM (SELECT a.VehicleOwner,
      COALESCE(a.City, (Select b.City from a INNER Place b), 
              (Select b.City from a INNER   Place b)) AS City
      FROM VehicleMileage a) AS b
WHERE b.VehicleOwner IN (SELECT VehicleOwner 
                     FROM VehicleMileage 
                     GROUP BY VehicleOwner
                     HAVING COUNT(*)>1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
SELECT
    VehicleOwner,
    COALESCE(CarMileage, MotorcycleMileage, BicycleMileage, 0) AS Mileage,
    Count(*)
FROM
    VehicleMileage
Group by VehicleOwner, COALESCE(CarMileage, MotorcycleMileage, BicycleMileage, 0)
Having Count(*)>1
```

You can also put each column from COALESCE in GROUP BY section. Depends on what you want to achieve

Comment: how about if i have Coalesce(CarMileage, (SELECT MotorcycleMileage from...))?? Thank you!

Comment: @Andrew - Then you have to specify each column. You cannot have a subquery in a GROUP BY. `GROUP BY CarMileage, MotorcycleMileage, BicycleMileage`. But I don't think you will have the same output as in first case.

Comment: That's my point. How to do it else? having a subselect in coalesce? I have somthing like this: Coalesce(cy.Name, (SELECT co.Location from placei), (SELECT co.Location from place2))

Comment: I would avoid a subquery in COALESCE. Can you join the tables? I suppose the subquery is from another table than VehicleMileage. If join them, you will have a simple COALESCE as you posted initially.

Comment: I just saw the rest of your comment. It's hard to tell what you can do without knowing tables' schema. Something like: `select column1, COALESCE(Name, c.Location, d.Location) FROM Table1 JOIN placei c on c.key=Table1.key JOIN place2 d on d.key = Table1.key GROUP BY column1, COALESCE(...`

Comment: It doesn't work specifying each column, it gives me the following error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    VehicleOwner,
    SUM(COALESCE(CarMileage, 0)+COALESCE(MotorcycleMileage, 0)+COALESCE(BicicleMileage, 0)) AS Mileage,
    COUNT(*) cnt
FROM VehicleMileage
GROUP BY VehicleOwner
HAVING cnt > 1
```